# SpringData does not close connections?

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, tomcat7, spring-data-mongodb

I am facing some issues since I deployed my app a couple of weeks ago!

I found that Spring Data gets Mongo down after some time of use and printed this message:

"desc": "can't call something : vdbmongo1/10.20.0.211:27017/V1; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: can't call something : vdbmongo1/10.20.0.211:27017/V1"

First we saw there were too many open files, we used debian 7 which has a limit of 4096. We increased that number and doubled to 8192 all open files (If I am right, connections in linux are sockets, same that files, don't they?)

Increasing that value shoots up usage of memory, then we increased memory too, but we do not have so much memory available and the vm shuts down.

Finally we set a cron service to restart each 6 hours while we try to get a solution and it seems to work for now.

My app is deployed in a tomcat 7.0.28 running on Debian 7.

This is the piece of my xml to create the mongo instance:

```
<!-- MongoDB host -->
<mongo:mongo host="${mongo.host.name}" port="${mongo.host.port}" write-concern="SAFE">
     <mongo:options
         connections-per-host="40"
         threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="1500"
         connect-timeout="15000"
         auto-connect-retry="true"
         socket-timeout="60000"
         write-number="1"
         write-timeout="0"
         write-fsync="true"/>
</mongo:mongo>
```

We restarted the server this morning and here is how threads evolved:

```
Time             Threads (files)          Connections           RAM
09:00:00          90                       4                      177
10:00:00          7371                   78                  411
10:35:00          12519                 106                 480
11:00:00          14375                 113                 485 
11:40:00          16616                 122                 490
12:00:00          22776                 144                 584
12:30:00          26544                 156                 594
13:00:00          30251                 167                 600
13:40:00          39179                 191                 827
14:00:00          44075                 203                 855
15:13:00          60491                 239                 891
15:41:00          61976                 242                 904
16:00:00          64491                 264                 931
16:10:00          68619                 255                 939
16:20:00          70200                 258                 971
16:30:00          73416                 264                 1123
16:45:00          73959                 265                 1130
```

when I see the processes in vdbmongo1 any of those 73959 processes looks like :

```
mongod  30859 32763  mongodb  327u   IPv4           1646841     0t0     TCP vdbmongo1:27017->vtomcat1:60329 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod  30859 32763  mongodb  328u   IPv4           1647673     0t0     TCP vdbmongo1:27017->vtomcat1:60330 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod  30859 32763  mongodb  329u   IPv4           1646867     0t0     TCP vdbmongo1:27017->vtomcat1:60650 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod  30859 32763  mongodb  330u   IPv4           1646913     0t0     TCP vdbmongo1:27017->vtomcat1:60762 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod  30859 32763  mongodb  331u   IPv4           1648224     0t0     TCP vdbmongo1:27017->vtomcat1:60962 (ESTABLISHED)
mongod  30859 32763  mongodb  332u   IPv4           1647197     0t0     TCP vdbmongo1:27017->vtomcat1:32923 (ESTABLISHED)
```

where vdbmongo1 is the machine which contains the database and vtomcat1 the one where tomcat is deployed.

is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is normal / expected behaviour.

MongoDB will use as much memory as possible as it will mmap() the datafiles directly into memory, as well as using memory for every connection (default 1MB per connection)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that update to last mongo version (2.4.8) solved the problem. Now I cannot see more than 15 - 20 connections at the same time.